# php visitor counter not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem with mysql. My php code is not working.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("Unable to connect to the database");
mysql_select_db("visitor_counter") or die("Database is not created");
$find_counts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_count");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_counts))
{

 $current_count = $row['counts'];
 $new_count = $current_count + 1;
 $update_count = mysql_query("UPDATE 'visitor_counter' . 'user_count' SET
'counts'=$new_count");

}

?>
```

I have tested putting some echo on my codes. Once i put the echo code on the while loop the echo doesnt work. Can anyone help me.

Comment: You're using quotes where you shouldn't be, in this line `("UPDATE 'visitor_counter' . 'user_count' SET
'counts'=$new_count")`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` that will signal errors in your code. It's an easy fix-it-yourself. ;-)

Comment: first of all you should use mysqli or pdo

Comment: the problem is in logic of the loop. why You select whole table, then making update queries looping it also without passing WHERE parameter? 
If it's important to update counters in whole table just do Your update in 1 sql, then select whole table with 1 sql

Answer (score 0):

Use single query:

```
UPDATE `visitor_counter`.`user_count` SET `counts`=`counts`+1;
```

then do your SELECT ... FROM

because passing variable into sql query for this kind of operations are not always safe

and here is Your code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("Unable to connect to the database");
mysql_select_db("visitor_counter") or die("Database is not created");

mysql_query("UPDATE `visitor_counter`.`user_count` SET `counts`=`counts`+1");

$counts = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_count");
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $counts[$data['id']] = $data['counts'];
}
?>
```

Comment: *"because passing variable into sql query for this kind of operations are not always safe"* - Um... that's not the main reason why OP's code is failing. It's the quotes.

Comment: I know, I'm just trying to say that write safe code, for future use.

Comment: That downvote did `not` come from me, should you be wondering.

Comment: I know.
Everyone has rights to do this. :) it's ok.

Comment: I always give a reason when I downvote. The ones that do downvote, should give a reason why in order to improve it.

Comment: I love to know that I'm wrong and I learn from making mistakes. But downvoting without whys is not honest. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("Unable to connect to the database");
mysql_select_db("visitor_counter") or die("Database is not created");
$find_counts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_count");
$current_count = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_counts))
{
 $current_count = $row['counts']; 
}
$new_count = $current_count + 1; 

$update_count = mysql_query("UPDATE 'visitor_counter' . 'user_count' SET
'counts'=$new_count");
```

Comment: This will fail. `("UPDATE 'visitor_counter' . 'user_count' SET
'counts'=$new_count")`

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying here ?

```
mysql_query("UPDATE 'visitor_counter' . 'user_count' SET 'counts'=$new_count");
```

whats the table name ?

i guess your tablename is `user_count`

or do you have more than one tablename you like to update ?!?!?

if tablenam eis `user_count` it should look like

```
$update_count = mysql_query("UPDATE user_count SET counts={$new_count}");
```

so the total while would be

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_counts))
{

 $current_count = $row['counts'];
 $new_count = $current_count + 1;
 $update_count = mysql_query("UPDATE user_count SET counts={$new_count}");

}
```

### Important

Dont use

> 'tablename'

in your sql query... if you like to declair a tablename use

> `tablename`

Answer (score 0):

Check if your SELECT query works by change the code:
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_count") or die(mysql_error());

Check if there is data in de table user_count and edit the query:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_counts))
{
    print_r($row); //to print the database row
    $current_count = $row['counts'];
    $new_count = $current_count + 1;
    $update_count = mysql_query("UPDATE user_count SET counts=".$new_count); // no need to specify the database, you already did with mysql_select_db.
```

}

Comment: This will also fail `("UPDATE 'user_count' SET 'counts'=".$new_count)`

Comment: I forgot to delete the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Dont need to specify DB, and quotes are wrong, change to:

```
$update_count = mysql_query("UPDATE user_count SET counts = $new_count");
```

You also might want to specify a page:

```
$update_count = mysql_query("UPDATE user_count SET counts = $new_count WHERE page = '$this_page'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm really surprised to see everybody here posts code using the old and deprecated `mysql` functions (although some of them stated this is wrong). I would like to advice you **AGAINST** using `mysql` functions - they are deprecated as of [version 5.5](http://php.net/mysql_connect). You should use either `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. In my opinion, you should be using `PDO` as it provides support for almost all databases and you could use prepared statements.

Now to your code - I'm not quite sure why would use a cycle to count all of the records in the `counts` column. A much better way to do this is by using `atomic increment` - it will also guarantee your counter is properly incremented in case two queries are trying to increment the value simultaneously. Although you haven't posted your table structure, I believe something like this should do the work:

```
<?php

// Database connection settings
$db_host = '127.0.0.1';
$db_name = 'visitor_counter';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = 'root';

// Try to connect to the database
try {
    $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name;
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass);
} catch ( PDOException $e ){
    // Do something if connection could not be established
    throw new ErrorException("Could not connect to database!",0,1,__FILE__,__LINE__,$e);
}

// Find counts
// Assuming you have a user_id column in your `user_count` table.
$user_id = 1;

// Update counter
$update = $db->prepare('UPDATE user_count SET counter=(counter+1) WHERE user_id = :user_id');
$update->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$update->execute();

?>
```

P.S. In this code I'm assuming you're saving the visitor counter in the `user_count.counter` column and whenever somebody visits that user, the `counter` column is incremented for that specific user, rather than updating the counter for all users (as your code suggests).

Comment: the question wasnt "what is the best was to connect to a database?" thats why all help to find the issue and not coding him his project. actually the answere is right in a kind of way so i wont downvote it

Comment: technically you're right, but bad coding is simply bad coding... :)

Comment: i agree with that :) specialy when people start mixing html/php/css/js ^^